# Mostrar un registro de un listado

Tags: php, html

Estoy intentando hacer un botón de "mostrar" para cada elemento de un listado obtenido de base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cargo todos los registros en una tabla mediante un `while` y ése puede ser el problema porque siempre se queda con el último registro para mostrarme. Añado parte del código para que se hagan una idea:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE borrado='0' order by id DESC LIMIT $start_from, $registro_por_pagina";
$result = mysqli_query($enlace, $query);
?>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
     <tr>
      <!-- <th>ID</th> -->
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellidos</th>
      <th>Acciones</th>
     </tr>
     <?php
     $number=0;

   if ($result = mysqli_query($enlace,$query)){
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
         // $number++;

     ?>
     <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row["nombre"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["apellidos"]; ?></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $row["nombre"]; ?>"></td>
     </tr>
     <?php
     }
    }
     ?>
    </table>
```

Todo este código va dentro de etiqueta `<form>`:

```
<form action="mostrarusuario.php"  method="post">
<!-- .......codigo...... -->
</form>
```

He probado a poner en vez del `<input>` anterior éste:

```
<input type="submit" value="Mostrar Usuario completo" />
```

No tengo ningún problema en hacerlo con un `<select>` y un sólo botón, pero quiero que cada registro tenga el suyo.

¿Alguna idea? seguro que estoy haciendo algo mal pero no caigo.

Comment: ¿Cómo recibes en `mostrarusuario.php` el valor enviado por el botón? Es decir, ¿en qué índice de `$_POST` lo buscas? En principio, si te das cuenta, no le has puesto nombre al campo `<input>`,  por lo que no podrás acceder a su valor.

Comment: cierto, despues de tantos cambios lo he debido borrar. Lo paso por el nombre: name="nombre" y $_POST['nombre]. Bueno, o el "id", el mismo en todos los casos. GRACIAS

Comment: Bien, con todo eso ya tengo todo para poder redactar la respuesta.

Comment: Cuando puedas echa un vistazo a la respuesta que he creado. Si algo no funciona o tienes alguna pregunta no dudes en comentar la respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que estás creando múltiples campos `<input type="submit" name="nombre" value="..">` con diferentes atributos `value`, por lo que al enviar el formulario prevalecerá el último que exista.

Tienes dos soluciones:

- Crear un formulario por cada registro (la solución más fácil).
- Arreglar el problema a través de javascript.

### Un formulario por cada usuario

Es la solución más fácil:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row["nombre"]) ?></td>
    <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row["apellidos"]) ?></td>
    <td>
      <form action="mostrarusuario.php"  method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="nombre"
          value="<?= htmlspecialchars($row["nombre"]) ?>" />
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php
}
```

He creado un formulario por cada botón, por lo que ya no hay confusión en qué `<input>` tiene el valor correcto.

### Usando javascript

Para solucionarlo a través de javascript debes hacer más modificaciones. Te propongo crear un elemento `<input type="hidden">` donde almacenar el valor deseado una vez pulsado el botón:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row["nombre"]) ?></td>
    <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row["apellidos"]) ?></td>
    <td>
      <input type="submit"
        onclick="seleccionar(<?= htmlspecialchars(json_encode($row["nombre"])) ?>)" />
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php
}
```

Como puedes ver al pulsar el botón se ejecutará el evento `onclick` que llamará a la función `seleccionar()` pasando como parámetro el valor de `$row["nombre"]`. Si es una cadena de caracteres, `json_encode()` agregará automáticamente las comillas.

Tu formulario debe quedar así:

```
<form action="mostrarusuario.php"  method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="" />
<!-- .......codigo...... -->
</form>
```

Ahora debes implementar la función en javascript:

```
<script>
function seleccionar(valor) {
    let nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
    nombre.value = valor;
}
</script>
```

Cuando se pulse un botón, se asignará el valor entregado en el parámetro al campo oculto del formulario, que será enviado de manera habitual al PHP de destino.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Opté por javascript (era lo que estaba intentando, pero eres más rápido que yo).  Mil gracias por hacerme la vida más fácil, no sé que haría sin vosotros

Comment: Un placer ser de ayuda, aunque a mí gusto es más sencillo usar un enlace que pase por GET los datos. PD: si el campo "nombre" no es la clave primaria de la base de datos no deberías usarlo para identificar un registro.